# Python function behaves differently when i call it in another function loop

Tags: python

I'm working on a machine-learning code that calculate the cost function and gradient descent ,
I wrote every function separately as shown:

```
def costFunction(theta, X, y):
    
    m = y.size

    J = (1/m) * ( np.dot(-y,np.log(sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))))  -  np.dot((1-y),(np.log(1-sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))))) ) 
    
    return J
```

```
def gradiantDescent(alpha , theta , X , y , num_itr):

    m = y.shape[0]
    J_history = []
    theta = theta.copy()

    for _ in range(num_itr):
        
        tempZero = theta[0]

        theta -= (alpha/m) * (np.dot(X.T , (sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))-y)))
        theta[0] = tempZero -  ( (alpha/m) * np.sum((sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))-y)))

        J_history.append(costFunction(theta, X, y))

    return theta , J_history
```

and when i call the 'cost function' separately it's works as i expected:

```
intial_theta = np.zeros(X.shape[1])

J = costFunction(intial_theta, X, y):

print(J) # works as expected
```

but when i call it in gradiantDescent function all J_history will be 'nan' value:

```
theta , Jvec = gradiantDescent(0.05, intial_theta , X , y , 500)

print(Jvec) #all values are 'nan'
```

So how can i fix it.

Comment: when you call `gradiantDescent` do you call `costFunction` before that?

Comment: No, first i call gradiantDescent and it doesn't work as i expected, so i call cost function separately to see if it work and it work correctly as it shown before. @illusion

Comment: In your code only theta[0] is getting updated. Shouldn't it run for all the thetas in theta array?

Comment: Or rather you are updating only one weight. Shouldn't you update all of them?

Comment: It's already run for all thetas. as the RHS in (theta = ...) is an array with shape(5,) so the theta array updated in every iterate, and i update theta[0] separately because it should take another value not as the other indices

Comment: I'm subtracting array from array

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `gradiantDescent` function:

```py
for _ in range(num_itr):
    theta = theta - (alpha / m) * np.dot(X.T, (np.dot(X, theta) - y))
    J_history.append(costFunction(theta, X, y))
return theta, J_history
```

You get a `nan` value because some calculations are going wrong...

Comment: you are right theta values are going wrong, you alerted me to this point, i tried to find the error and it was the minus operand  '-'. I changed it to numpy.subtract() and it's work correctly, Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

The minus Operand was the error in calculating theta, Should use numpy.subtract(arr1, arr2)
Old Code:

```
theta -= (alpha/m) * (np.dot(X.T , (sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))-y)))
```

New:

```
np.subtract( theta ,(alpha/m) * (np.dot(X.T , (sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))-y))) )
```